# Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 FBPlacePickerViewController table with Pull To Refresh

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, uitableview

I'm trying to implement Pull-To-Refresh such as https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh inside `FBPlacePickerViewController` `tableView`.

Unfortunately the Pull-To-Refresh view doesn't appear inside the `tableView`

```
@interface PlacePickerViewController : FBPlacePickerViewController
```

```
            [self.tableView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
            [self.tableView.pullToRefreshView performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
        }];

        [self.tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
            NSLog(@"load more data");
        }];
```

Has anyone tried this before?

Thanks!

Comment: This is vague.  Put the piece of code up that creates the PTR view.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used SVPullToRefresh but I did look at the code and compare it with what we are using.  We have a simple subclass that wraps the controller our UITableView is in and it adds drop-in PTR support. It seems a little easier to use that the SV implementation

Codes is as follows:

**PullToRefreshViewController.h**

```
//
//  PullRefreshTableViewController.h
//  Plancast
//
//  Created by Leah Culver on 7/2/10.
//  Copyright (c) 2010 Leah Culver
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
//  obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
//  files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
//  restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
//  copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
//  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
//  Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
//  conditions:
//
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
//  included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
//  EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
//  OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
//  NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
//  HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
//  WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
//  FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
//  OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface PullRefreshTableViewController : UITableViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIView *refreshHeaderView;
    UILabel *refreshLabel;
    UIImageView *refreshArrow;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *refreshSpinner;
    BOOL isDragging;
    BOOL isLoading;
    NSString *textPull;
    NSString *textRelease;
    NSString *textLoading;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *refreshHeaderView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *refreshLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *refreshArrow;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *refreshSpinner;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *textPull;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *textRelease;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *textLoading;

- (void)setupStrings;
- (void)addPullToRefreshHeader;
- (void)startLoading;
- (void)stopLoading;
- (void)refresh;

@end
```

**PullToRefreshViewController.m**

```
//
//  PullRefreshTableViewController.m
//  Plancast
//
//  Created by Leah Culver on 7/2/10.
//  Copyright (c) 2010 Leah Culver
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
//  obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
//  files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
//  restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
//  copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
//  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
//  Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
//  conditions:
//
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
//  included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
//  EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
//  OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
//  NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
//  HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
//  WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
//  FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
//  OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "PullRefreshTableViewController.h"

#define REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT 52.0f


@implementation PullRefreshTableViewController

@synthesize textPull, textRelease, textLoading, refreshHeaderView, refreshLabel, refreshArrow, refreshSpinner;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
  self = [super initWithStyle:style];
  if (self != nil) {
    [self setupStrings];
  }
  return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  if (self != nil) {
    [self setupStrings];
  }
  return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self != nil) {
    [self setupStrings];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self addPullToRefreshHeader];
}

- (void)setupStrings{
  textPull = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull down to refresh..."];
  textRelease = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Release to refresh..."];
  textLoading = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Loading..."];
}

- (void)addPullToRefreshHeader {
    refreshHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - 320)/2, 0 - REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT, 320, REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT)];
    refreshHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //[refreshHeaderView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    refreshLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT)];
    refreshLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    refreshLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
    refreshLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    refreshLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    refreshArrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
    refreshArrow.frame = CGRectMake(floorf((REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 27) / 2),
                                    (floorf(REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 44) / 2),
                                    27, 44);

    refreshSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    refreshSpinner.frame = CGRectMake(floorf(floorf(REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 20) / 2), floorf((REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 20) / 2), 20, 20);
    refreshSpinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

    [refreshHeaderView addSubview:refreshLabel];
    [refreshHeaderView addSubview:refreshArrow];
    [refreshHeaderView addSubview:refreshSpinner];
    [self._tableView addSubview:refreshHeaderView];
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (isLoading) return;
    isDragging = YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (isLoading) {
        // Update the content inset, good for section headers
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0)
            self._tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= -REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT)
            self._tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
    } else if (isDragging && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
        // Update the arrow direction and label
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT) {
            // User is scrolling above the header
            refreshLabel.text = self.textRelease;
            [refreshArrow layer].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
        } else { // User is scrolling somewhere within the header
            refreshLabel.text = self.textPull;
            [refreshArrow layer].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI * 2, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (isLoading) return;
    isDragging = NO;
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT) {
        // Released above the header
        [self startLoading];
    }
}

- (void)startLoading {
    isLoading = YES;

    // Show the header
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self._tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT, 0, 0, 0);
    refreshLabel.text = self.textLoading;
    refreshArrow.hidden = YES;
    [refreshSpinner startAnimating];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // Refresh action!
    [self refresh];
}

- (void)stopLoading {
    isLoading = NO;

    // Hide the header
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(stopLoadingComplete:finished:context:)];
    self._tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    [refreshArrow layer].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI * 2, 0, 0, 1);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)stopLoadingComplete:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    // Reset the header
    refreshLabel.text = self.textPull;
    refreshArrow.hidden = NO;
    [refreshSpinner stopAnimating];
}

- (void)refresh {
    // This is just a demo. Override this method with your custom reload action.
    // Don't forget to call stopLoading at the end.
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopLoading) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [refreshHeaderView release];
    [refreshLabel release];
    [refreshArrow release];
    [refreshSpinner release];
    [textPull release];
    [textRelease release];
    [textLoading release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try an alternative: [ODRefreshControl](https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl). Very simple to setup and use.